# Netty ChannelGroupFutureListener operationComplete never called

Tags: netty

I have the following definition for a server based on Netty documentation [example](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html):

```java
public void start() throws Exception {

    incommingGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    final ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

    serverBootstrap.group(incommingGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(final Channel channel) throws Exception {
                    final ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

                    pipeline.addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler());

                    pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder",
                            new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { '\r', '\n' }),
                                    Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { '\n' }),
                                    Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { ';' })));

                    pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder());
                    pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder());

                    pipeline.addLast(new TrackerChannelOutboundHandler());

                    pipeline.addLast(new TrackerChannelInboundHandler(/* eventAdmin */notificationService));

                    channelGroup.add(channel);
                }
            }).option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, Boolean.TRUE)
            .option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
            .childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);

    final ChannelFuture cf = serverBootstrap.bind(notificationService.port());

    final Channel channel = cf.channel();

    channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup("group-gpstracker", GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
    channelGroup.add(channel);
}
```

I want to write some message to all clients like this (method of the same server class):

```java
public void write(TrackerMessage trackerMessage) {

    ChannelGroupFuture result = channelGroup.writeAndFlush(trackerMessage, ChannelMatchers.isNonServerChannel());

    result.addListener(new ChannelGroupFutureListener() {

        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelGroupFuture arg0) throws Exception {
            LOGGER.info("Some info");
        }

    });
}
```

The `TrackerChannelOutboundHandler` implementation is:

```java
public class TrackerChannelOutboundHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {

    if (ctx != null && ctx.channel() != null && ctx.channel().isWritable()) 
        ctx.writeAndFlush(trackerMessage.getMessage() + "\n");

}
```

}

The message is received at clients successfully, but why is the `operationComplete` method of the `ChannelGroupFutureListener` never called?

I am using Netty version: 4.0.40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When extending a `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter`, it's important to make sure all native interactions with the channel are properly propagated. This should be done by respecting the `ChannelFuture`s and `ChannelPromise`s.

At the moment, you are ignoring the upstream `ChannelPromise`, preventing any upstream success notifications from being delivered, hence why your future is never being marked as success.

You should use either the superclass implementation, or the `ctx.write(Object, ChannelPromise)` method to properly pass your message to the upstream, and in the case of an error, you should manually mark the future either as failed, or successful, depending on your intentions.

```java
@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {
    if (ctx != null && ctx.channel() != null && ctx.channel().isWritable()) 
        super.write(ctx, trackerMessage.getMessage() + "\n", promise);
    else
        promise.setFailure(new java.util.concurrent.CancellationException());
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what was missing! Thanks!